# useEffect and fetching data

Tags: reactjs, api, callback, frontend, backend

so I'm trying to fetch some data from the backend to determine the route the member will reach when he/she logins.

I'm using useEffect to do so but I'm failing to fetch the data before the rendering of the page.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (primaryRole === 'asap-dept-member') {
        apiService.ApplicationService.getMemberApplication(asapUser.id).then(response => {
            response
                .filter(application => application.applicant.user.id === asapUser.id)
                .forEach(res => {
                    setArray(res);
                    setApplication(res.id);
                });
        });
    }
}, [asapUser.id, primaryRole]);

if (array !== null && primaryRole === 'asap-dept-member') {
    console.log(application);
    initialRoute = routesMetadataForRole[2]?.path.replace(':id', application);
} else {
    initialRoute = routesMetadataForRole[0]?.path;
}
```

this is the API call

```
static getMemberApplication() {
    return $axios.get(`application/member/`, { headers: authHeader() }).then(response => response.data);
}
```

and the problem I'm trying to solve is that I'm getting undefined before getting the application number.

[image]

any suggestions on solving it?
I know that I need to use an async function but every time I try it I'm getting the same result.

Comment: http://localhost:3000/#/application/view/undefined that's the route I'm getting instead of http://localhost:3000/#/application/view/71

Answer (score 0):

you should be using an async function try the following

```html
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchApi() {
      return apiService.ApplicationService.getMemberApplication(asapUser.id);
    }
    fetchApi().then((response) => {
       response
                .filter(application => application.applicant.user.id === asapUser.id)
                .forEach(res => {
                    setArray(res);
                    setApplication(res.id);
                });
    });
  }, [asapUser.id, primaryRole])
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your comment. I'm still getting the same result I don't know why. it's still undefined before it updates.

Comment: http://localhost:3000/#/application/view/undefined that's the route I'm getting instead of http://localhost:3000/#/application/view/71

Comment: have you tried to log the response after the promise is fulfilled is it displaying all the time after then try to log the response plus note that the useEffect will re-render each time the passed items in the params array are changed so this could be a problem

Answer (score 0):

Axios will return a promise. You have to listen to the promise and then execute the setstate. You can read more about the promise [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). I personally use async/await(suger coating for promises).

```
    const fetchData = async () => {
    if (primaryRole === 'asap-dept-member') {
            const data = await apiService.ApplicationService.getMemberApplication(asapUser.id);
            // now compute on the data...
             data.filter.....
             .forEach.....
            });
        }
    }, [asapUser.id, primaryRole]);
    
    if (array !== null && primaryRole === 'asap-dept-member') {
        console.log(application);
        initialRoute = routesMetadataForRole[2]?.path.replace(':id', application);
    } else {
        initialRoute = routesMetadataForRole[0]?.path;
    }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    })
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your comment. I'm still getting the same result I don't know why. it's still undefined before it updates.

Comment: http://localhost:3000/#/application/view/undefined that's the route I'm getting instead of http://localhost:3000/#/application/view/71

Comment: What is `array` variable here? Maybe, there is some error in the conditions?

Comment: to check if there is any application for this user. if the array is not empty it means there is an open application for him.